# Estimative in Hs spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider $W(t)$ defined by $\widehat{W(t)} = (2 \pi)^{\frac{-n}{2}} \cos (t|\xi|)$. Consider $g \in H^{s-1} (R^{n-1})$. Show that:

$$ \| W(t ) *g\|_{H^s} \leq c \sqrt2  (1 + |t|)\| g\|_{H^{s-1}}$$
where c is a constant

I dont have idea to how to do that. someone can give me a hint?
thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a typo?  It is not true if $t=0$.  I don't think it is true for any $t>0$ either.